# Issue with margin around navbar using html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a demo portfolio (still in the very beginning stages) using html and CSS. I'm having an issue with my navbar having margins on all sides, even though I've set the global margin to 0 on my stylesheet. My goal is to have the navbar span the width of the viewport with no margin around it (except for the bottom). I haven't had this issue before, so any and all advice is appreciated!

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="Personal Portfolio Stylsheet.css">
        <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul type="none">
                <li href="#About">About</li>
                <li href='#Work'>Work</li>
                <li href='#Contact'>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <body>
        <section id="welcome-section">
            <h1>Liam McBride</h1>
            <h2><i>Web Developer</i></h2>
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="contact-info">
            <h1>Reach out to me at any of the following links:</h1>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond|Roboto&display=swap')

 /* To call fonts, use the following:
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Box sizing border box means that padding and border width are included in the total width for all elements. */

:root {
    --color-off-white: #fff6f6;
    --color-aluminum: #c4c4c4; 
    --color-charcoal: #494646;
    --color-black: #1f1919;
    --color-navy: #6385b1;
    --color-deep-water: #1a3861;
}

#navbar{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-navy);
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

nav>ul {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:1.15em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0.5em 0.7em 0.1em 50em;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: So some quick things; `header` needs to be a child of `body` (I know, doesn't make sense semantically but that's how it is and what's probably causing your current issue), also `ul` doesn't have a `type` of `none` just disc, circle, or square (maybe you meant to do this css as `list-style: none` ?) and I'd avoid using `position: relative` unless there's absolute positioned elements inside it or it's otherwise necessary. Also would be helpful to move your example to the code editor instead of as snippet. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Didn't realize that about header--really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set the body and nav>ul margin to 0

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond|Roboto&display=swap')

 /* To call fonts, use the following:
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
margin:0;}
/* Box sizing border box means that padding and border width are included in the total width for all elements. */

:root {
    --color-off-white: #fff6f6;
    --color-aluminum: #c4c4c4; 
    --color-charcoal: #494646;
    --color-black: #1f1919;
    --color-navy: #6385b1;
    --color-deep-water: #1a3861;
}

#navbar{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-navy);
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

nav>ul {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:1.15em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0.5em 0.7em 0.1em 50em;
  margin:0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="Personal Portfolio Stylsheet.css">
        <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul type="none">
                <li href="#About">About</li>
                <li href='#Work'>Work</li>
                <li href='#Contact'>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <body>
        <section id="welcome-section">
            <h1>Liam McBride</h1>
            <h2><i>Web Developer</i></h2>
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="contact-info">
            <h1>Reach out to me at any of the following links:</h1>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why only setting the global and navbar margins didn't do the trick?

Comment: it's the ul under the navbar that had some margin.  not sure why your global didn't work